# Terminated App only being restarted one time

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, appdelegate

I have an application that by design should be activated by the OS after a location event is delivered from the system even if the app has been terminated. Terminated can mean terminated by the system or by the user in the multitasking switcher. My app delegate code is below and the location delegate is an extension of the app delegate class. The first event that is generated by the system after the app is terminated is delivered to my app and processed properly, but I am not receiving any subsequent events. Is there some code I need to run after the event is received to reregister my application for future updates?

```
var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var notificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter?
    var today:String?     //Today's date format: YYYY-MM-DD


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {

            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()
            self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            sendTestNotification()
        } else {
            print("normal launch")

        }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but your code is wrong: if all you want to do is monitor visits, you do not need to, and should not, set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You say your app has been "terminated". This suggests that you *kill* your app intentionally as a way of testing. But if an app has been forcibly terminated, the system deliberately stops background location monitoring, so naturally you won't get any more visit monitoring events. It is as if you had called `stopMonitoringVisits` yourself.

Comment: This is not the behavior I am seeing. If I force close the app using the multitasking pane, then the application still receives the next location update, but does not receive any updates after that.

Comment: And I’m saying that’s expected.

Answer (score 0):

app terminate is not allow by apple as i know.

```
exit(0)
```

you can use that code line to app terminate